# How to show all the data changes since the last commit in Ember data?

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I know that Ember data's model has the `isDirty` attribute, but how can I use it to show a list of all the changes/deltas of the data since the last commit?

Tom Dale's talk ([listen until 36:44](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=djhAsWGOImk&t=35m32s)) mentioned that it is possible to tweak the [adapter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=djhAsWGOImk&t=30m)([github](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/83f9f6b9124612d3ac0b8ab34ad98b6028800138/packages/ember-data/lib/system/adapter.js), [api](http://www.thomasboyt.com/ember-data-docs/classes/DS.Adapter.html)) or [serializer](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=djhAsWGOImk&t=31m) ([github](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/83f9f6b9124612d3ac0b8ab34ad98b6028800138/packages/ember-data/lib/system/serializer.js), [api](http://www.thomasboyt.com/ember-data-docs/classes/DS.Serializer.html)) hooks to do that. Can anyone give me an example?

current research: I'm using the local storage adapter which adds stuff to the [dirty set](https://github.com/rpflorence/ember-localstorage-adapter/blob/master/localstorage_adapter.js#L152), which I think might be what I want. It is found in the [ember data store](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/83f9f6b9124612d3ac0b8ab34ad98b6028800138/packages/ember-data/lib/system/store.js#L1563), [ember data adapter](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/83f9f6b9124612d3ac0b8ab34ad98b6028800138/packages/ember-data/lib/system/adapter.js#L472), [ember data relationship changes](https://github.com/emberjs/data/blob/83f9f6b9124612d3ac0b8ab34ad98b6028800138/packages/ember-data/lib/system/changes/relationship_change.js). I am trying to figure out how everything fits together to show the data changes.

Answer (score 0):

If it's any help, Ember Data stores the new (unsaved) values of attributes in the model's _attributes hash. It's quite internal though so you might want to be careful with it - I would n't recommend manipulating it directly.